# Old TV Show with creatures who could hear your heart beating

Tags: story-identification, tv

The other day I had remembered and old show/movie that I had watched as a kid that actually gave me nightmares back in the day. I'm fairly certain I watched this about 30 to 35 years ago (so, early 80's).

What I do remember about it is this:

- It was black and white (*maybe* technicolor), but confident it was probably black and white.
- There were humanoid creatures (perhaps similar to shades, or horsemen?)
- They could hear your heartbeat.

One scene (if I remember correctly) a man had ran across a field into a shed, or barn and was hiding, but as he was trying to be quiet the sound of his heart beat grew louder and he was afraid the creatures would hear it.

I vaguely remember him panicking and covering his chest to try to cover the sound of the beating.

One other thing I remembered, I watched it on regular cable in the US.

Comment: It's in color and from the early 70s but maybe [*Tombs of the Blind Dead*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMcbfKZSvI0) rings a bell?

Answer (score 2):

Could this be [Tombs Of The Blind Dead](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067500/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) (1971)? [This review](https://www.theweekender.com/moviereviews/11117/b-movie-corner-the-blind-dead-can-hear-your-heart-beat) mentions the 'hearing heartbeats' angle.

> The film revolves around the Knights Templar (a fictionalized version
>   of a real-life order that was dissolved in the 14th century following
>   charges of witchcraft and heresy) coming back from the dead as
>   reanimated corpses bent on revenge. However, the corpses are blind
>   because their eyes were pecked out by birds while their hanged bodies
>   rotted on the gallows.
>
> **Despite being blind they have exceptional hearing and are able to hear
>   the human heart beating, thus making it nearly impossible to hide from
>   these hell-bent creatures.**
>
> Meanwhile a young couple on vacation takes a train journey, but his
>   girlfriend argues with him, jumps off the train and spends the night
>   in the ruins of an abandoned monastery where the Templars are buried.
>   However, this is the worst time possible as this is the night that the
>   Templars rise from their tombs and kill her.

**Warning: This film has NSFW elements and terrible acting throughout.**

Comment: Warning: link is mildly NSFW (half-naked lady on fire is the worst I've seen so far). Also, catfights and not-to-be-taken-out-of-context female cries.

Comment: Maybe? I did a quick skim through and nothing was ringing a bell. I will check it out this evening and watch it in full to see if this was it. The description sure does fit. I could have sworn what I watched was black and white. I could be wrong

Comment: I almost think it fell into the twilight-zone type of flick. I believe there were several spin offs of the twilight zone shows, but I can't remember what they were called

Comment: That's like if Monty Python made a cheap soft porn film.  It's so over the top cheesy you think it has to be a parody.

Comment: I watched the entire thing. Quite interesting. I don't think that is is though. I mean, this was 30 years ago, so my memories may have collided with other tv shows. One thing I do remember now, is it would have been available on regular cable back in the 80's in the US